# Probability of a dice board game

Tags: probability, dice

So, I'm playing a board game in which there are **5 dice** (which you roll at once), **3 ships** and a probability of hitting one ship with one die of **2/6**.

My question: What is the probability of hitting all 3 ships using the 5 dice?

So far I've got this: $$P=\biggl(\frac 2 6\biggr)^3 + \biggl(1-\frac 35\biggr)\biggl(\frac 2 6\biggr)^3 = 0.051852 $$

Is it good?

Comment: This is not clear.  What outcomes determine which ships are hit?

Comment: Sorry. One ship is hit if one die shows a 5 or 6, thus 2/6.

Comment: If we consider standard dice and you hit when you roll $5$ or $6$, do you hit all three ships any time at least three dice come up $5$ or $6$?

Comment: Please edit your question to add this rule.  So this is a binomial process with $p=\frac 13$ and you are asking for the probability of at least $3$ successes out of $5$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes, I have to get a 5 or 6 on three separate dice to hit them all

Comment: Not sure I can.

Comment: Well, read up on [the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)...that article contains an explicit formula for this sort of question.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll read through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your $\left( \frac 26\right)^3$ is the chance the first three dice come up hits.  I don't understand the logic of the $\left(1-\frac 35\right)$  You can either count the chance you get exactly $3,4,5$ and add or count the chance you get $0,1,2$ and subtract from $1$.  To get $5$ hits is $\left( \frac 26\right)^5$.  To get three is ${5 \choose 3}\left( \frac 26\right)^3\left( \frac 46\right)^2$ because you choose which three dice will hit, those come up right $\frac 26$ of  the time and the others have to miss.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: oh ok i got it .